# Does Kotlin have Something Similar to Swift's perform(#selector) and NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget:)

Tags: android, kotlin

In Swift I can use the following code to call a function in 7 secs but I can also cancel it at anytime before the 7 secs it up. Does Kotlin offer anything similar?

```
// 1. call showTimeoutErrorLabel 7 seconds from now
perform(#selector(showTimeoutErrorLabel), with: nil, afterDelay: 7)

// 2. cancel the above perform() so that it won't fire off showTimeoutErrorLabel
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
// or
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(showTimeoutErrorLabel), object: nil)

// the actual function
@objc func showTimeoutErrorLabel() { ... }
```

I found some `Kotlin` posts on `Handlers`, `Timers`, and `Executors`, but nothing on how to cancel them and recall them later if necessary.

Comment: I might've found the answer using a `job` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61019647/4833705

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61019647/4833705)

```
var job: Job? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        ensureActive() // edited my answer to include this. Read @GabeSechan's comments below
        delay(7000L)
        showTimeoutErrorLabel() // or as another example change the color of buttonA
    }

    binding.cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
        cancelJob()
    }
}

fun cancelJob() {
    job?.cancel()
}

fun showTimeoutErrorLabel() { ... }
```

Comment: That will work but you ought to use `lifecycleScope` instead of GlobalScope so it will automatically cancel the job when the Activity is destroyed, to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: So a few tings on that:  that code would cause it to run the coroutine on the main thread.  If you're doing UI stuff that's good.  If you're not, you may not want that.  Or you may, it all depends.  The second is I'm not certain your cancel would work.  YOu've already launched the coroutine.  The delay is on the coroutine, not done before it's launched.  So it can't be canceled without the coroutine checking for cancellation itself and stopping itself.

Comment: The reason it can't be canceled from the outside without it helping is the same reason you can't safely kill a thread from another thread-  you don't know the state, so attempting to do so could lead to deadlock or worse.  The reason it works on iOS is that what you're doing there is setting a timer and running some code in 7 seconds.  Here you're running a function that waits 7s then runs some code.  You need to put a check to see if it's been canceled before calling showTimeoutErrorLabel, or the cancel won't work.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the `lifecycleScope`. I just tried the code on a button color. In `OnCreate` after 7 secs I change the button color. But I have another button that cancels the job. When I press the button the cancels the job, the button color never changes. This is of course on a brand new activity before the color changes, not the same one after the button color has already changed. I'll make a small edit to my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @GabeSechan You're right about the cancellation issue. I just found a post that explained what you said https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067420/4833705. It says to use `ensureActive()`. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because you're mixing the language and the OS enviornment it runs on.  Kotlin doesn't have anything, because Kotlin doesn't have the concept of a timer.  Neither really does Swift.  That's a part of the OS library you're looking at, if you tried to write Swift on Windows it may not exist.

So each of the things you mentioned in your post can be canceled.  They all get canceled in different ways.  For a handler you'd use removeCallbacksAndMessages().  That will remove anything that was posted to the handler if it hasn't already been processed.  For a timer, you call cancel() on it.  Which you should use depends on what you're trying to do, they all have different pluses and minuses.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm just learning Kotlin so things that are intuitive to me in iOS are hazy in Kotlin. I just found `coroutines/job`, tested it, and it works fine. I posted the answer below. Assuming there aren't any unforeseen drawbacks, it's easy to use to.